# How to get the progress meter of curl for HTTP requests without redirecting the curl stdout to a file?

Tags: curl

When I run

```
curl example.com > example.html
```

on the terminal, I get the progress meter as follows

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  1256  100  1256    0     0   1950      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1947
100  1256  100  1256    0     0   1950      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1947
```

According to https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html it is necessary to redirect the curl stdout to a file in order to have this message displayed.
"If you want a progress meter for HTTP POST or PUT requests, you need to redirect the response output to a file, using shell redirect (>), --output or similar."
If I run

```
curl example.com 2> progress.txt
```

there is no data in `progress.txt`. Therefore I need to run

```
curl example.com > example.html 2> progress.txt
```

How can I access the progress meter without redirecting the curl stdout to a file?

Answer (score 1):

If you pipe the data to another program, you’ll get the progress meter. A basic

```
curl example.com | cat
```

works, but with longer results you’ll run into the issue mentioned in the documentation:

> it *disables* the progress meter as otherwise it would mess up the output mixing progress meter and response data

To avoid that, use `sponge` (from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/), available in most distributions):

```
curl example.com | sponge
```